# Is there a way to make a universal Javascrpit variable on a website and access it and change it via C# app

Tags: javascript, c#

I have no website design experience and I have a friend that will make a website for me, however when I told him about making an API or C# app that can access a variable in the website let's say like users count he said that he never heard of that, maybe I didn't ask correctly but I know that there is a way to count how many users my C# has and store it in a server that shows that variable on a website page
Hope you help me, thnx in advance
PS. I thought of something like this.

```
API.Changeviable("users", CurrentUserID);
```

Comment: Webserver are computer and store data on disks; therefore any information must sit in files not 'variables'. Maybe a cookie file?

Comment: there are many ways to count visits /views of a website, storing data to files (not recommended) or database. Making C# access variables in javascript is NOT a solution is bad design

Comment: Add an HTTP endpoint for your C# variable and use fetch() in JS to get it

Answer (score 0):

The general answer is Yes, it's possible, but it depends on the technology you are using.

You can do this if your page is rendered on the server (like old ASP.NET WebForms). 
Or, for example, if you are using brand new ASP.NET Core Blazor.
But, in any case, you have to use a kind of UI (User interface) technology where frontend code is formed on the server side.
For example, you can call the `[JavaScript function in your Blazor app][1]`

If you want to use the "clear" WebAPI, you must be understanding that the javascript function calls the server API endpoint (function) first. And only after this C# code (or any other language) returns some value.

Of course, API endpoint c# code CAN return a string with JavaScript code (which changes your variable) inside, and then JavaScript caller function can parse this string and execute the code, but such approach is not safe.